# How to display ActivityEvents based on a URL, and not on the current user?

Tags: development, social, activity-feed

For a community site, I want to displayed activities that happen on the current site. The requirement is to have activities displayed in several places:

- On the user's profile and other users' profiles (I think I got this one)
- On the community's home page.

I'm having some trouble with the latter...
I can get activities by using the [ActivityManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.activityfeed.activitymanager_members.aspx) class, but it only has methods that relate to a specific user... I would like to use the same infrastructure to display activities for the current site.

Is this at all possible? Activities to have the [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.activityfeed.activityevent.link.aspx) property, but it doesn't look like it does much...

What alternatives are there? I'm thinking about creating all events in another database so I can easily track them, but that seems wasteful. I can also iterate over all community members and get their activities, but I doubt that would be performant.